# Filter a list (ul>li) using dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, drop-down-menu, filter

I have this code below that filters a list based off a selected radio button ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qmjjL3x/2/)).

How do I change it, so I can use a drop down list to filter it ( select>option tags) ?

```
<input name="name" value="_a" id="_a" type="radio"/><label for="_a">A</label>
<input name="name" value="_b" id="_b" type="radio"/><label for="_f">B</label>
<input name="name" value="_ab" id="_ab" type="radio" checked="checked"/><label for="_ab">A and B</label>
<br>
<select>
    <option value="_a">A</option>
    <option value="_b">B</option>
    <option value="_ab">A and B</option>
</select>

<ul id="mylist">
<li class="_ab _a">A1</li>
<li class="_ab _a">A2</li>
<li class="_ab _b">B1</li>
<li class="_ab _b">B2</li>
</ul>
<script>
$('input').click(function() {
        var selector = $('input:radio').map(function(){ 
            return this.checked ? '.' + this.id : ''; 
        }).get().join('');
        console.log(selector);  

        var all = $('li[class^="_"]');
        if(selector.length)
          all.hide().filter(selector).show();
        else all.show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: put the question up front, improved the wording, linkified jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener to the "select" tag. Look into [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) specification.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {

        var selector = "."+$(this).val();
        console.log(selector); 

        var all = $('li[class^="_"]');
        if(selector.length)
          all.hide().filter(selector).show();
        else all.show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qmjjL3x/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
        var selector = $('option').map(function(){ 
            return this.selected ? '.' + this.value : ''; 
        }).get().join('');
        console.log(selector);  

        var all = $('li[class^="_"]');
        if(selector.length)
          all.hide().filter(selector).show();
        else all.show();
    });
```